# Kafka KSQL Tumbling window

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am trying to understand and work through some examples on KSQL . I have confluent community edition(6.0.0) installed in my local machine.

I have below  table in KSQL

```
sql> DESCRIBE TUMB;

Name                 : TUMB
 Field    | Type                           
-------------------------------------------
 EMAIL    | VARCHAR(STRING)  (primary key) 
 AMOUNT   | DOUBLE                         
 CURRENCY | VARCHAR(STRING)
```

and I am using python producer to producer data in this topic / table.When I try to aggregate over tumbling window using below SQL

```
CREATE TABLE pageviews_per_region_per_minute AS
>  SELECT CURRENCY,
>         COUNT(*)
>  FROM TUMB
>  WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 1 MINUTE)
>  GROUP BY CURRENCY
>  EMIT CHANGES;
```

I am getting error - "Windowing not supported for table aggregations."

I looked up this video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fUOi9wJPhk where similiar thing was done however there was no error .  I looked up at the ksql document at https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/aggregate-streaming-data/  and syntax seems to be alright.I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your ksqlDB version, this should be fine in the latest version of ksqlDB (0.14.0). Confluent Platform 6.0.0 or 6.0.1 only contains 0.10.0.

Not that you’re using Confluent Cloud, but just to note that also uses the latest version of components so it too is using 0.14.0.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming TUMB is a table due to it has a PK.
You cannot create a windowed table/stream from a table, you need an STREAM as source of the aggregation.
Try define TUMB as stream.